# Difference between the VNLD5300 and VNLD5090

Tags: mosfet-driver

I have been looking for a low-side mosfet driver IC and found these [VNLD5300](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/f4/89/6a/f4/63/53/4b/28/DM00056965.pdf/files/DM00056965.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00056965.pdf) which is a 300mOhm 2A driver and the [VNLD5090](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/25/e0/94/0e/0b/e8/40/5f/DM00055363.pdf/files/DM00055363.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00055363.pdf) which is a 90mOhm 13A driver. I would like to do one last sanity check, the 5090 seems to be a much more superior IC am i right? But what strikes me is as weird for the same package can the 5090 really handle that current? they are priced very close too so i assumed that ST electronics made these 2 version intentionally with different purposes.

My application is controll and inductive coil at 1.5A both IC fit the application, would going for the 13A 5090 good for me ? What could the reason be that there is a skew with an inferior rating, because i dont think its cost, since they are priced that close.

Answer (score 0):

They should indeed to be functionally identical, with the VNLD5090 having a more powerful internal switch and better (lower) thermal resistance. But it also does have a larger gate charge which you may need to consider, especially if you are switching at a high frequency.

The high current is possible due to the low RDSon, which means less (thermal) power dissipation in the switch.

Comment: I would like to think the difference is in the impedance